# How to pass data in a stateful widget with constructor?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I am new to flutter and I think I miss a little piece of information about constructor and stateful widget. I tried many ways but always have an error. I just want to pass data into my stateful widget to manipulate from there.

Here is my Error

```
The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Here is my code

```
class CreateEducatorEventForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime day = DateTime.now();
  final String favoriteId = '';

  CreateEducatorEventForm(DateTime day, String favoriteId);

  @override
  _CreateEducatorEventFormState createState() =>
      _CreateEducatorEventFormState();
}

class _CreateEducatorEventFormState extends State<CreateEducatorEventForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _eventName = '';
  String _eventDescription = '';
  DateTime _eventDateStart = widget.day;
  DateTime _eventDateFinish = widget.day;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move it into `initState`

```
class _CreateEducatorEventFormState extends State<CreateEducatorEventForm> {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    bool _isLoading = false;
    String _eventName = '';
    String _eventDescription = '';
    DateTime _eventDateStart;
    DateTime _eventDateFinish;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        _eventDateStart = widget.day;
        _eventDateFinish = widget.day;
    }
}
```

Comment: it say the getter day was called on null. Maybe there is a little mistake in the logic

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, unless you really need to store this into your state (say, if it really participates in the lifecycle of your widget), you should just refer to it via `widget.day` whenever you need it.

Comment: Yes i really need it, it's a form widget that display data when the form is loaded.

Comment: Right, but remember you can still refer to `widget.day` in your `build()` function. Now if you need to change it via `setState( () { _eventDateStart = ... } )`, then using `initState()` like @Evan stated in his answer is the way to go.